# How to perform mathematical operations?

Tags: c++, math

I have been given the following assignment and am unsure how to implement it:

> Calculate the fee for a taxi ride. The formula is as follows:
>
> The first kilometer costs 50. Each extra 200m costs 5. If the distance
>   is more than 30km then each extra kilometer adds 10 to the fee. The
>   program has to input the total distance (in km) and calculate the
>   charge.

I wrote the following code but don't know what to do with "200m costs 5" part...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    double totalfee, km, m;
    cout << "distance" << endl;
    cin >> km;
    m = km * 1000;
    if (km < 30)
    {
        totalfee = 50;
        cout << "totalfee = " << totalfee << endl;
    }
    else if (km > 30)
    {
        totalfee = 60;
        cout << "totalfee = " << totalfee << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

> it is in c++

Comment: C **XOR** C++? Where's all the whitespace?

Comment: Learn how to use % operator. And we are not here to solve your problem, just to help you. BUT ((km%200)*5)  should be a tip

Comment: The lack of whitespace makes your code _very_ hard to read.

Comment: Seems a mathematical issue, not a programming one.

Comment: @demonofnight - i dont think thats right, its a divide not a remainder that he needs. (km-50)/0.2 * 5

Comment: @all thanks for giving me some idea :)

Comment: @pm100 yeah u r rite i used divide and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the question contains some ambiguities - we know that the first km costs 50, and any 200m above the first km adds an additional 5. However, if the distance is greater than 30km, is the 10 per km fee additional on top of the 5, or does it replace the 5? Additionally, should partial amounts count e.g. is 5 charged if the total distance is 1100m? I'll assume that a partial amount does not count.

Secondly, you have some logic errors in your code. This block:

```
if (km < 30)
    {
        totalfee = 50;
        cout << "totalfee = " << totalfee << endl;
    }
```

Ignores the extra 5s that you should be charging above the first 1km.

The next block:

```
else if (km > 30)
    {
        totalfee = 60;
        cout << "totalfee = " << totalfee << endl;
    }
```

Contains the same logic error as the first, but also ignores the extra 10 to charge for each km, only charging this once (and charging it when it shouldn't at all, e.g. if the total km is 30.5).

You could try something like this:

```
//Assuming the two fees are both added separately from one another:

totalfee = 50; // Charge at least this much no matter what

// Pseudo-code:
if (km > 1)
{
   // Subtract 1 from km
   // Divide result by 0.2, discard any remainder
   // Multiply result by 5, and add the total to totalfee
}
if (km > 30)
{
   // Subtract 30 from km
   // Divide result by 1, discard any remainder
   // Multiply result by 10, and add the total to totalfee
}

cout << "totalfee = " << totalfee << endl;
```